# How to Deploy React frontend with laravel backend to cpanel/hosting

Tags: reactjs, laravel, deployment

I have laravel backend+frontend website hosted in my hosting. now I want to replace frontend with React Js, but backend will be same laravel. now where can i deploy my react code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.